# viewing log.d output from a delphi macos project in release mode

Tags: delphi, logging

In debug mode, my Delphi 11.3 MacOS project correctly sends output from Log.d() to the PAServer.

How do I view Log.d() output when the app is running outside of Delphi, built for release?

Comment: Please refer to the "macOS and iOS section" [here](https://docs.code-kungfu.com/books/debugging-tips-and-tricks/page/adding-log-calls-to-your-code-and-how-to-view-them), regarding using Console to view logs

Comment: @DaveNottage The Console on MacOS does show a lot of messages coming from a new blank Delphi 11.3 project. However, Console does not show the messages from Log.D when running that same new blank app (with a single button that calls Log.D) from the MacOS Finder. The messages do appear in the PAServer when Delphi is running the project.

Comment: You're right - `Log.d` commands do not show in Console. This may be due to the macOS logging code in FMX using `Writeln`, instead of `NSLog`, like `TOSLog` from Kastri does.

Answer (score -1):

Take a test using this tool, [DataLogger](https://github.com/dliocode/datalogger). There is a provider called DataLogger.Provider.OutputDebugString - it will do what it needs..

Comment: `DataLogger.Provider.OutputDebugString` uses the same mechanism as `Log.d`, ultimately resulting in using `Writeln`